# Description column in Apache's directory listing

Tags: apache

What is it for, and can you add a description manually?

`<meta name="description" content="didn't do anything"/>`

[image: Description column in Apache's directory listing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are expected to add the description using `mod_autoindex`'s [AddDescription directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription).